# How to replace all words that contain a certain string in notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I'm struggling to figure out how to replace full words containing certain strings, i have been searching and trying for a small while but anything i come across either doesn't work or replaces far too much,

to give an example of what i need exactly, if we have a text lets take a part of the lyrics from bones as an example.

```
My patience is waning
Is this entertaining?
Our patience is waning
Is this entertaining?
```

i want to be able to replace every word that contains "ing" with something else for example "boop", this should result in,

```
My patience is boop
Is this boop?
Our patience is boop
Is this boop?
```

my problem mainly lies in the fact that everything i try only replaces the "ing" or everything infront of it aswell and not only the word that contains it.

Comment: Is `ing` always at the end of the word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to also replace words with `ing` in the middle of a word, use:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `[a-z]*ing[a-z]*`
- Replace with: `boop`
- **UNTICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
[a-z]*      # 0 or more letters
ing         # literally
[a-z]*      # 0 or more letters
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

##### Like this:

Find: `\b\w+ing\b`

Replace `boop`

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/chGUHb/1)**

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `\b` | the boundary between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char |
| `\w+` | word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `ing` | 'ing' |
| `\b` | the boundary between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char |

Comment: This find also works `\w*(ing)\w*`

Comment: Yes, but it consume a capture group, that is not needed in my version (lightweight)

Comment: You can omit the leading `\b` :-)